# PHP regex match multiple pieces

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regex and I know the basics of how to pull out one sub string from a given string but I am struggling to get out multiple parts that I need. I am wondering if someone could help me with this simple example and then I work my way from there.  Take this string:

> *LMJ* **won** *Neu*. **Zone -** *KEN* #*55* *LEIGH* vs *LMJ* #*63* *ONEIL*

The parts in italics are the parts of the string that will change and bold will stay the same in every string.  The parts I need out are:

1. First team id which in this case is `LMJ`, this will always start the string and be 3 uppercase letters, `^[A-Z]{3}`?
2. The Neu part which could be one of 3 strings, `Neu`, `Off`, `Def`, `[Neu|Off|Def]`?
3. The second team part which will come always after the word `Zone -`, `[A-Z]{3}`?
4. Need the numeric part of the string after the first `#`.  This could be 1 or 2 digits `[0-9]{1,2}`?

5.Third team part same as 3 except will appear after `vs`, `[A-Z]{3}`?

6. Same as 4 need numeric part after 2nd `#`, `[0-9]{1,2}`?

I would like to put that all together into one regex is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside square brackets is a so-called character class: it matches only a single character. so, `[Neu|Off|Def]` means: exactly one of the characters `N`, `e`, `u`, `|`, `O`, `f` or `D` (repetitions are ignored)

What you want is a capture group: `(Neu|Off|Def)`

Putting it together:

```
^([A-Z]{3}) won (Neu|Off|Def)\. Zone - ([A-Z]{3}) #([0-9]{1,2}) [A-Z]+ vs ([A-Z]{3}) #([0-9]{1,2}) [A-Z]+$
```

(This assumes you're not interested in the "LEIGH" and "ONEIL" parts, and these are always in upper case letters)

Comment: Thanks Roel.  Worked perfect on a few examples I tried.  Going to try and use this example to create a few more regex strings.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be something like;

```
'/([A-Z]{3})\ won\ (Neu|Off|Def)\.\ Zone\ -\ ([A-Z]{3})\ (\#[0-9]{1,2}\ \w+)\ vs\ ([A-Z]{3})\ (\#[0-9]{1,2}\ \w+)/'
```

() are used for capturing the different parts.

This is not tested properly.